# Trouble calculating attribute values in pyqgis

Tags: qgis, python, fields-attributes

I recently posted another question about calculating unique IDs for features using python and qgis here [Calculating unique ID value for a field in QGIS using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138180/calculating-unique-id-value-for-a-field-in-qgis-using-python). I am trying to use the same technique of iterating over features from two different layers, check if they intersect, and if they do, calculate the values for a field in one layer using the values from a field in the intersecting layer. The code runs without error, but no values are calculated. It is a string field that I am trying to calculate values for. The `b` features are polygons and the `s` features are points. When I step through I find that they are intersecting (as expected) and the NumVal prints as expected. Can anyone help? Here is a snippet of the code:

**UPDATE:** Based on the answer I have edited the code below, which now functions as expected. I have highlighted the line that missing previously.

```
                        idxBuffNm = dsslvExplodeLyrWGS84.fieldNameIndex('SiteName')
                        idxCsvNm = shpWnames.fieldNameIndex('SITE_NAME')

                        #Start editing Buffer layer -
```

this was the missing line:

```
                        dsslvExplodeLyrWGS84.startEditing()
```

now follows the rest of the code

```
                        for b in dsslvExplodeLyrWGS84.getFeatures():
                            for s in shpWnames.getFeatures():
                                if s.geometry().intersects(b.geometry()) == True:
                                    NmVal = s.attributes()[idxCsvNm]
                                    b.setAttribute(idxBuffNm,NmVal)
                                    dsslvExplodeLyrWGS84.updateFeature(b)

                        dsslvExplodeLyrWGS84.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Are they in the same spatial reference? the geometry.intersects has difficulty if they're not *exactly* the same spatial reference. That sounds like it's not the problem here as stepping is getting the correct values (so you say) is the layer locked by another application/process? Shouldn't you be editing on dsslvExplodeLyrWGS84? i.e. dsslvExplodeLyrWGS84.startEditing().

Comment: oh good grief that was the problem. Thank you for pointing that out I have been looking at this for too long

Comment: Can't see the forest because of all the trees... done that before! Perhaps put that in as an answer to your own question and get yourself some easy rep.

Comment: good idea thx!!

Comment: Please include your updated code in your answer, as it stands it's a bit short. Make sure you point out the line that has changed for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Miles-Stimson pointed out in his comment above, I was not editing dsslvExplodeLyrWGS84 but a different layer, that was the problem. It's good to have another set of eyes.