# setAttributes() with list values

Tags: pyqgis, list

In a script on PyQGIS, after a `for` cycle, I obtain a `list` like:

```
LIST:, [[[0], 0.035, [0], [0], [0], [0], 0.036, 0.031]])
```

I need to put that values in the column of Shapefile Attribute Table, but I'm not able to do this, and the result is only a series of 0,000.

Can anyone help me find the error?

Final part of the script:

```
    for p in int_points:
        valore = prov_raster.identify(
            p,QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue).results()[1]
        ang_OBSTd = [0]
        difelev = (valore - valore_iniz)
        if (difelev) >= 200:
            values.append(valore)
            distanza = values.index(valore)*xsize  
            tana = (valore / distanza) 
            tan_a.append(tana)

            ang_OBSTd = np.degrees(np.arctan(np.max(tan_a)))
        else:
            values.append(0)

LIST.append(ang_OBSTd)
angle = [LIST]
feat.setAttributes([i, angle, value[idx_lines[i]],direction[k]])
feat.setGeometry(geom)
```

[image: sample]

Comment: There's a basic script I put together https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138180/calculating-unique-id-value-for-a-field-in-qgis-using-python/138188#138188 . I don't see where you're updating the feature, are you committing the changes?

Comment: What do you bean with "committing the change"? I updated the script adding the FOR cycle with ang_OBSTd calculation.

Comment: Have a close look at the linked script. You've changed the attributes and the geometry of the feature **but you haven't told QGIS to update the existing geometry** A.K.A. 'save' the changes to the feature, then you also need to **tell QGIS to update the layer** otherwise all your changes are lost.

Comment: Now I understood the issue about "update/write" the list values on Attribute Table.... but basically should I put a sort of  "dsslvExplodeLyr.updateFeature(f)" from "feat.setAttributes" and
"feat.setGeometry" to do that?

Comment: Yes, to **update the feature** (the geometry is just a value in the table) you need to call dsslvExplodeLyr.updateFeature(f), assuming your parent layer is dsslvExplodeLyr. The object you're setting fields on is a copy of the feature, held in memory, you have to instruct QGIS to commit the changes to the existing feature **and also to the shapefile** with dsslvExplodeLyr.commitChanges() to ensure the changes that have been made to the features are saved. There's a double buffer there (layer and feature) which I think has something to do with python representations of C objects.

Comment: But I don't have an existing shapefile to update; I'm writing a new shapefile with: _uri = "LineString?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + \"&field=id:integer&field=angle:double&field=value:integer""&index=yes"_ And it write and **memorize** correctly columns ID, VALUE but **NOT** ANGLE

Comment: I see, you're creating the features, not updating existing ones. What field type is angle? Are you sure that difelev (which is valore - valore_iniz) >= 200? Can you insert print('valore {}, diffelev {}'.format(valore,diffelev)) before the if statement then run to ensure that the condition is being met? Are you sure the the point p is in the same spatial reference and falls on prov_raster?

Comment: The angle is a double field. Difelev is >=200 for many values. If i make that print command before if, I obtain (...difelev 135.0, value 295.0; difelev 264.0, value 424.0; difelev 240.0, value 400.0...). If i Make a print of LIST at the end i obtain the correct values I want write in attribute as ANGLE (('LIST:', [[], [], 25.763405462345659, 53.122840860636728, 53.122840860636728, 53.122840860636728, [], []])) but I can't only write them in the table!!! Why this?